# PT 8 - pt 10 hardware

Tags: post-production

I’m moving from Protools LE 8 Digi rack 002 to protools 10.
When I upgrade do I continue to use the digi rack 002 hardware or do you just use a good soundcard instead.
Or what is the way to do it.
I also use a two track editor, can you play back from that and protools if you just have a sound card.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the 002R will work fine with PT10, I too use it and all is fine.However come Pro tools 11 it is unlikely that the 002R will work. Avid have announced that the 002 family amongst others will no longer 'supported' after PT10. However what is not clear is if it will continue to work. Other 'unsupported' hardware like ProControl still works OK.

Comment: i imagine it will still show up through "aggregate i/o" (as long as your computer recognizes the device and can communicate with it). it probably means there will be no new drivers; which means it might not be functional with future Windows or Mac operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is something you should ask on the Avid forums (DUC).
Also I recommend to check the faq's on the Avid website.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the 002 Rack with Pro Tools 10. I do.

You'll need to download the updated drivers though. They can be found [here](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/download/en379411?popup=true), under the "Firewire Device Drivers" heading. Install those **before** updating to 10.